# RxSwift observe frame vs bounds

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift, frp

I intend to add a UIView instance onto ViewController's view and observe the change of it's frame/bound. But the difference between `frame` and `bounds` confused me, code in `viewDidLoad` like below:

```
let v = UIView()
view.addSubview(v)
v.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
    make.edges.equalToSuperview()
}

v.rx.observe(CGRect.self, #keyPath(UIView.frame))
    .subscribe(onNext: { print("frame: \($0!)") })
    .disposed(by: rx.disposeBag)
v.rx.observe(CGRect.self, #keyPath(UIView.bounds))
    .subscribe(onNext: { print("bounds: \($0!)") })
    .disposed(by: rx.disposeBag)
```

the default option of `observe` method is `[.new, .initial]` and it will log out like this:

```
frame: (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
bounds: (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
bounds: (0.0, 0.0, 375.0, 667.0)
```

So why `bounds` could emit the initial and new value but `frame` only the initial value?

Comment: Why do you need to observe the bounds/frame of your views ? The problem may be there

Comment: I wanna do something with the back layer and it depends on the size.

Comment: Wait ‘viewDidLayoutSubviews’ or ‘layoutSubviews’ in a custom UIView subclass. The frames/bounds are monitored by AutoLayout, you should not interfere in elsewhere than in the dedicated methods.

Comment: @GaétanZ You're right, it should do in the `viewDidLayoutSubviews` or `layoutSubviews`. But here what confused me is the difference between `bounds` and `frame`, as we know that the `bounds` determines the `frame` and since the size of  `bounds` changed ,the `frame` should be changed as well.

Comment: The reason is that the frame is calculated from the bounds & the center of your view. AutoLayout only sets those properties.

Comment: @GaétanZ So when the `bounds` changed the `frame` should be changed as well, but no new value emitted for the change of `frame`.

Comment: It changes but you are not notified because the “set” is not directly called

Comment: @GaétanZ I checked the documentation of Apple, the `frame` is something like computed property which is determined by the `bounds` and `center`, so when `bounds` changed the `frame` will be changed only if you call getter of `frame`. Thank you!

Comment: I saw yesterday that frame also takes into account the transform property

Comment: @GaétanZ You're right, transform/affineTransform also influence the frame